# Java Program Architecture: IO Buffer

Tags: java, arraylist, architecture

I am new to Java and wrote a program which is very difficult to update because business logic, modal and repo data is combined in the classes. I have since researched many tutorials but I cannot find the answer to ensure my program is written in the most resource efficient manner.

The program imports 1 line of a CSV via BufferedReader class and creates a modal object instance to reflect each column read. However then a second CSV sheet is read via BufferedReader to check if any of the data from the first CSV matches, then updates the modal object with this new information.

Then once the updated modal object is updated, the updated modal objects are added to an ArrayList.

Which architectural way is more efficient, version 1 or version 2 and why:

**VERSION 1**

1. READ LINE
2. CREATE OBJECT INSTANCE
3. READ LINE
4. UPDATE OBJECT INSTANCE (& RUN LOGIC)
5. WRITE LINE (OBJECT) TO NEW FILE VIA BUFFEREDWRITER
6. REPEAT 3000 TIMES

**VERSION 2**

1. READ LINE
2. ADD TO ARRAYLIST A
3. READ LINE
4. ADD TO ARRAYLIST B
5. RUN LOGIC BY COMPARING ARRAYLIST A AND B
6. WRITE FINAL ARRAYLIST TO NEW FILE VIA BUFFEREDREADER

Please note, that although this is currently using CSV data with a limited number of lines (3000), in future the CSV lines will increase to over 50,000 lines of data, so is it better to add to ArrayLists and run logic on the complete ArrayList, or to run logic on each object first, then add the complated objects to ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2 is more efficient because you're batching operations, and you're not repeating expensive tasks. A classic example of that is a database connection - establishing a database connection is generally expensive, so opening a connection and doing 100 updates through it is always more efficient (for the caller) than opening connection, doing an update, closing connection x 100.

The trade-off with that example is that databases can only hold a finite number of connections, so doing a 100 updates through one connection is more efficient for the caller but might block other callers to the database.

Using a buffer is another "expensive" operation, that's why version 1 is so much slower, because you're setting it up 300 (50,000) times rather than once.